# Contest math: Proving that an equation has four real solutions

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Problem: Let $3/4<a<1$ 
Prove that the equation $x^3(x+1)=(x+a)(2x+a)$ 
 has four distinct real solutions and find these solutions in explicit form. 
 My Approach: 
 The equation may be rearranged as:
$x^4+x^3-2x^2=3ax+a^2$ 
 After trying some values we notice that 2 of the roots are in the ranges $(-2,-1)$ and $(1,2)$. How do I find the other two solutions?

Comment: Even if you have shown roots exist in certain ranges, the question still wants one to find them explicitly, i.e. obtain expressions for them which are in terms of the parameter $a.$

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432633/what-are-the-conditions-on-a-such-that-the-polynomial-x4-2ax2xa2-a-has?rq=1).

Comment: For quartics, the contests often write something which can be found to be a difference of squares. This one comes out to be $$     (x^2 + \frac{x}{2})^2  - (\frac{3x}{2} + a)^2      = x^4 + x^3 - 2 x^2 - 3ax - a^2   $$  from which quadratic factors may be found. Seems the answers in Dietrich's link don't include this intermediate step, difference of squares.

Comment: added:  if the quartic for which the roots were required came out as $$ 5 (7 x^2 + 11 x +13)^2 - 17(19x+23)^2 $$  the factoring would not be evident to the naked eye, but could be found from the two terms $  (7 x^2 + 11 x +13) \sqrt 5 $   and $(19x+23) \sqrt{17} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^3(x+1) = (x+a)(2x+a) \iff (x^2+2x+a)(x^2-x-a)=0$ (considering it as a quadratic in $a$).

Now given that $a \in (\frac34, 1)$, the discriminants of the quadratic (in $x$) in the factorisation above are $4-4a, 1+4a > 0$, hence there are always two real values of $x$ for each of these factors.

--
P.S. Including the explicit representations below (use the quadratic formula on each factor):
$$x \in \left\{-1\pm\sqrt{1-a}, \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4a}}2,  \right\}$$